# How to extract ths sfx script from a file?

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have a packed auto-extract sfx file that runs the script.
Is it possible to extract the script code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. It depends on the exact format of the archive. zip is easy since the file format has 1) a well-defined start signature, and 2) a directory at the end of the archive. Most tools that can handle zip archives could open such a sfx archive readily. For other formats it may not be so easy.

Comment: The exe-archive file  contains some programs installations files, so when I run the exe it unpacks everything and installs every this unattended. So I want to extract the source of this script.

Comment: I am almost sure that this is sfx script but not 100%, what else can it be? NSIS?

Comment: "SFX" on its own is meaningless. It stands for "self-extracting", but does not give the archive format. Try passing `/?` or `/h` to the executable and see if it gives some clue as to the actual format.

Comment: when I run it, it displays an extracting a progress bar with 7zip sfx icon.
p.s. i tired to open this file with 7zip application but it didn't display the script that was used

Answer (score 1):

http://legroom.net/software/uniextract

Comment: how this can help me?